# How to fail a build on low code coverage using TFSBuild.proj file in TFS2012

Tags: code-coverage

We are implementing gated check-ins in our project and the core requirement is minimum code coverage should be 90%. I can fire my test cases after the build and also getting the code coverage. How do i set the threshold value check in TFSBuild.proj file

Comment: Why are you using TFSBuild.proj still? Why not use build definitions? They're much nicer and more flexible.

Comment: Yes it is, however its a legacy project using templates would be more time consuming at this stage.

Comment: Ok, though FYI, depending on how complex the .proj file is, going to the default template can be pretty easy.